# Difficulty installing dbt snowflakes using pip

Tags: dbt

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
  Failed to build pyarrow
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
I tried installing dbt-snowflake but having this error. Can anyone help please?
```

Comment: Hi - your question would be easier to understand if you hadn’t repeated the same information with apparently random formatting. Please could you update your question so that it clearly shows 1) the command you are running 2) the full error you are getting 3) any additional information that might be useful to someone who is trying to help you e.g. what are you trying to do, what is your environment setup, etc

Comment: Please do take a look at [the guidelines for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To help, we'd really need to know what you've tried so far to resolve this error. `pip` is telling you that the installation failed, because it needs the `pyarrow` library to work, and installing that failed - have you tried `pip install pyarrow` directly? What did you find when you googled the error?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, dbt compatibility is up to python version 10. If you recently downloaded version 11 of python, it may cause unexpected behavior or errors. You need to install version 10 of python and attempt to reinstall dbt in a virtual environment using version 10.

Reference dbt docs here https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/core/install-python-compatibility.

Comment: dbt now supports python version: 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11.
https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/core/install-python-compatibility